# how to use [] and [^] together?

Tags: regex

i want to accept letters from range `b-g` > `[b-g]+`

i want to accept letters not in range `a-z` > `[^a-z]+` while accepting range `b-g`

i tried `^([b-g]+[^a-z]+)$` on my string `12bcdefg34`

has allowed `bcdefg` > `[b-g]+`

and allowed `1234` > `[^a-z]+`

but it do not match the string because regex tries to apply her form but i want to only accept these letters so i want something like this `^[b-g^a-z]+$` is that possible?

Comment: consider clarifying your question
you're negating the entire lowercase alphabet with [^a-z]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to match anything that's either (1) not a letter or (2) specifically a letter in the range b-g. So how about just `[^ah-z]+`?

In general there's no way to combine two regular expressions into a new one that means both are true (AND semantics); there's only alternation (OR semantics). Though you can sometimes fake AND with lookahead or lookbehind, there's usually a better solution.